# TimerTask not initiating in a for loop (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, timer, timertask

I'm fairly new to java only starting this year, sophomore year in high school, I am currently working on a side project and can't get this block of code to work, I know where it's not working I just need help knowing why.

```
public Timer[] t = new Timer[3];

public TimerTask tt[] = new TimerTask[3];

public int ttc = 0; 
public int[] hasBought = new int[3];
public int[] j = 1;

public void run()
{
    for(;ttc<3; ttc++)
    {
        System.out.println(ttc+"a");
        tt[ttc] = new TimerTask()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        System.out.println(ttc+"b");
                        count += (j*hasBought[ttc]);                            
                    }

                };

        System.out.println(ttc+"c");
        t[ttc].scheduleAtFixedRate(tt[ttc] , 1000, 1000);
    }
```

From what I currently know this should all run fine and print 0a 0b 0c 1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c and it should also start 3 timers but it is printing 0a 0c and coming up with a NullPointerException error. The 2nd part makes sense because the TimerTasks obviously aren't being initialized because it isn't printing 0b.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what is causing the problem but I'm guessing it is something to do with these lines:

```
tt[ttc] = new TimerTask()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
```

**EDIT**

I'm not having problems with a NullPointerException, I know what one is and how to fix it, I don't understand why the TimerTask isn't initiating.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your stack trace and point out the relevant lines.

Comment: what is `hasBought` ?